# If statement skipping else if straight to else

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm attempting to make the statement below do the following.
If age is greater than 20 and less than 50, continue.
If age is less than 20 and greater than 50, error restart.
if anything else, error, restart.

But, for some reason it skips right over the else if condition and goes straight to else. If I input "19" for age, it outputs "Error.", if I input 51 for age, it outputs "Error." Whats up?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int plyAgeCreate() {

    int plyAge = 0;

    cout << "Enter an age" << endl;
    cin >> plyAge;

    //If age is greator than 20 and less than 50, accept.
    //Else if age is less than 20 but greator than 50, decline.
    //else, error. Restart.

    if (plyAge >= 20 && plyAge <= 50) {
        cout << "Welcome!" << endl;
    }
    else if (plyAge < 20 && plyAge > 50) { //Why is this being skipped?
        cout << "Between 20 and 50" << endl;
        return plyAgeCreate();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        return plyAgeCreate();
    }



}


int main()
{

    plyAgeCreate();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You have `if(plyAge < 20 && plyAge > 50)`. What number is less than 20 **and** more than 50 at the same time?

Comment: I appreciate that, I'm just new trying to figure out whats up. It really helps to hear from others and see examples, this code isn't critical for anything it's just me trying to get a feel for what I've read about and learn through experience. I'll check out your links, I haven't even started thinking about debugging yet, should help!

@PM77-1 oh my god

Comment: @PM77-1 Oh right, that's a lot more understandable. In your opinion I should create multiple else if statements to solve this? 
IE: else if (plyAge < 20) { too young, return function } else if (plyAge > 50) { too old, return function  } or would that just give me the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use or, not and. it will only go in there if the number somehow is less than 20 and more than 50, which is impossible. if it was 19 it would have to change to 51, either change it to this or delete it.

```
else if (plyAge < 20 || plyAge > 50) { //Why is this being skipped?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had been curios for some time the difference between the two, experiencing it and seeing them in action really sorts that out for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong logic:

> else if (plyAge < 20 && plyAge > 50)  // this condition can never be true

should be

```
else if (plyAge < 20 || plyAge > 50)
```

Comment: Man, it's as simple as that. Being new to this stuff is definitely an adventure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int plyAgeCreate() {

    int plyAge = 0;

    cout << "Enter an age" << endl;
    cin >> plyAge;

    //If age is greator than 20 and less than 50, accept.
    //Else if age is less than 20 but greator than 50, decline.
    //else, error. Restart.

    if (plyAge >= 20 && plyAge <= 50) {
        // This means Age is Between 20 and 50
    }
    else { 
       //This means age is below 20 OR above 50
    }    
    // There cannot another case. Either between 20 - 50 or not between 20 - 50
}


int main()
{

    plyAgeCreate();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```